# Understanding value assignment and data structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Could someone explain to me why

```
df[df %in% c("a", "b", "c")] <- NA
```

does not work?

I have found a work around by using lapply and splitting the dataframe into a list of columns but I want to understand what is happening here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `%in%` works only on `vector`/single column and not on the whole dataset.  We need

```
df[sapply(df, `%in%`, c('a', 'b', 'c'))] <- NA
```